# How to get the second sub element of every element in a list

Tags: r

I know I've come across this problem before, but I'm having a bit of a mental block at the moment. and as I can't find it on SO, I'll post it here so I can find it next time.

I have a dataframe that contains a field representing an ID label.  This label has two parts, an alpha  prefix and a numeric suffix.  I want to split it apart and create two new fields with these values in.

```
structure(list(lab = c("N00", "N01", "N02", "B00", "B01", "B02", 
"Z21", "BA01", "NA03")), .Names = "lab", row.names = c(NA, -9L
), class = "data.frame")

df$pre<-strsplit(df$lab, "[0-9]+")
df$suf<-strsplit(df$lab, "[A-Z]+")
```

Which gives

> ```
>    lab pre  suf
> 1  N00   N , 00
> 2  N01   N , 01
> 3  N02   N , 02
> 4  B00   B , 00
> 5  B01   B , 01
> 6  B02   B , 02
> 7  Z21   Z , 21
> 8 BA01  BA , 01
> 9 NA03  NA , 03
> ```

So, the first strsplit works fine, but the second gives a list, each having two elements, an empty string and the result I want, and stuffs them both into the dataframe column.

How can I select the second sub-element from each element of the list ? (or, is there a better way to do this)

Answer (score 129, accepted):

To select the second element of each list item:

```
R> sapply(df$suf, "[[", 2)
[1] "00" "01" "02" "00" "01" "02" "21" "01" "03"
```

An alternative approach using regular expressions:

```
df$pre <- sub("^([A-Z]+)[0-9]+", "\\1", df$lab)
df$suf <- sub("^[A-Z]+([0-9]+)", "\\1", df$lab)
```

Comment: what is the `"[["` doing in this example?

Comment: selects single elements of the list items, see ?"[["

Comment: @rcs this is fantastic, thank you so much! now i have a follow-up question: what if the 2nd element of each list item is a list, and you want to get, say, the third element of it?

Answer (score 13):

with purrr::map this would be

```
df$suf %>%  map_chr(c(2))
```

[for further info on purrr::map](http://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map.html)

Comment: Nice! The `c(2)` is a bit extra, so it can be simplified to `map_chr(2)`

Answer (score 4):

First of all: if you use `str(df)` you'll see that `df$pre` is `list`. I think you want `vector` (but I might be wrong).
Return to problem - in this case I will use `gsub`:

```
df$pre <- gsub("[0-9]", "", df$lab)
df$suf <- gsub("[A-Z]", "", df$lab)
```

This guarantee that both columns are vectors, but it fail if your label is not from key (i.e. `'AB01B'`).

Comment: RCS's answer actually answer my main question (how to returnt he second value from the list) but your answer seems to be more elegant for what I actually want.  Well done.

Comment: Could you please explain how the "[[" worked in sapply. The definition for sapply is stated at : http://www.inside-r.org/r-doc/base/sapply.

Answer (score 0):

You could select any item you want using `lapply`:

```r
df$suf<-lapply(df$suf,function(x) x[2])
```

An alternative approach using pipes:

```r
df$suf <- df$suf %>% lapply(function(x) x[2])
```